# Hibernate @ManyToMany mapping gives Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, many-to-many

So I have seen many questions similar to this, None seem to be similar to mine though.. So I am trying to understand Hibernate Mappings - (Stuck at ManyToMany) mapping.

So I want to make 3 tables, One with Student Detail, Second with Courses Offered and Third that stores students ID with respective course ID...

Here are the tables...

```
public class Student implements Serializable
{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="st_id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="StudentCourses", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="st_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="c_id")})
private HashSet<Course> courses = new HashSet<Course>();

// respective setter getters
}
```

The second class Course

```
public class Course implements Serializable
{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="c_id")
private Integer c_id;

@Column(name="c_name")
private String c_name;

@Column(name="c_fee")
private String c_fee;

// respective setter and getters
}
```

Now when I try to add a Course, It gives me the following Exception.
Please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'generalDAO' defined in file [G:\Kaustubh\Training\HibernateMapping\target\classes\com\bluetree\DAOImpl\GeneralDAOImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.bluetree.appConfig.ApplicationContextConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: com.bluetree.model.Student.courses
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'generalDAO' defined in file [G:\Kaustubh\Training\HibernateMapping\target\classes\com\bluetree\DAOImpl\GeneralDAOImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.bluetree.appConfig.ApplicationContextConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: com.bluetree.model.Student.courses
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at com.bluetree.test.TestMappings.<init>(TestMappings.java:25)
    at com.bluetree.test.TestMappings.main(TestMappings.java:63)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.bluetree.appConfig.ApplicationContextConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: com.bluetree.model.Student.courses
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: com.bluetree.model.Student.courses
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: com.bluetree.model.Student.courses
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.getCollectionBinder(CollectionBinder.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1899)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:913)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:740)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at com.bluetree.appConfig.ApplicationContextConfig.getSessionFactory(ApplicationContextConfig.java:63)
    at com.bluetree.appConfig.ApplicationContextConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$98c986dc.CGLIB$getSessionFactory$0(<generated>)
    at com.bluetree.appConfig.ApplicationContextConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$98c986dc$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e094f8d6.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at com.bluetree.appConfig.ApplicationContextConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$98c986dc.getSessionFactory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 28 more
```

Help would be much appreciated. Thank You.
This above code I was trying from the following [Link](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-many-using-annotations-1.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try too use interface reference instead of implementation i.e

```
private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<Course>();
```

Comment: @KaustubhKallianpur Can you approve my answer? It can be my first approved answer on stack ? :D

Comment: i'd be greatful if you could upvote my question too :P